# Jasmine testing with Backbone and jQuery

Tags: javascript, testing, backbone.js, jasmine

I was trying without success for many days, i would like to know how do you test with jasmine on backbone.js... i have an html file where the app is, and an app.js file where all the js is. I use localStorage to simply prototype the app.. the structure is more or less like the todo app, but I have some problems. First of all, how to test event calls? Secondly, how to, for example, add "todos" in the test without affecting the original app? I think that the problem of this kind of conflict reside in the localstorage maybe. how to avoid it? What kind of setup do you suggest? I checked out plenty of tutorials all over the internet but no one is  complete for my case and I can't really understand overall how jasmine tests click events..  Thanks for the help.